# A Table of Contents Page for a Scanned PDF

Tags: pdf, scanning

I was given some really old but very useful hand-written notes recently and in a bid to preserve them, I had them scanned into a file in the PDF format. What I have is a 35 page PDF but I want to add a contents page at the beginning so that I can use the first page to click my way to a specific topic.

More precisely,
I want a page which says

Topic 1

Topic 2

Topic 3
...

Each one should be linked to a page of my choosing.

I've explored a lot of standard tools out there to help me with this, like LibreOffice, pdftk etc. but the solution does not appear to be in the form of a simple application and a few clicks. My hunch is that this will require a program written in a suitable language. The way I'd want this program to work as follows:

```
ProgramName Input.pdf CustomTOC.txt
```

Where CustomTOC.txt could be a simple ASCII table containing two columns, one column being the title and the second column being the page number. The output of this program will be another PDF file which contains one page appended at the beginning of Input.pdf containing a table of contents with hyperlinks to the right pages.

Comment: How is this related to programming? If this is simply something you want to do with standard software, please ask on a different forum (such as superuser.com).

Comment: Well, I did a lot of searching for standard tools and did not find any answer. My strong suspicion is that the answer will come in the form of a custom program written in Python or a similar language. And yes, I do understand that the question does seem unrelated to programming, the way I have framed it. 

As of now, I am working on a solution that involves a Python script and once done, I will post it. Maybe before or after that folks here may want to offer more elegant solutions.

Comment: Forgot to add, if you do feel that the question does not really belong here, I can mark it for deletion. Else I can post my solution once I am done with it. Please let me know.

Comment: If you want to keep it on here, I feel it needs to be more related to programming (but I'm not the owner here :-)). I'd be fine if you mark it as a python problem and then make the problem you have more concrete in those terms. As it stands now I really feel it should end up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem though I don't think this is the best way to do it. I have written a Python program that accepts two mandatory inputs - the input PDF file and '|' separated ASCII table containing columns and page numbers. A third optional output can be the name of a PDF file which contains the output. If this is not provided then the original input file is rewritten.

***How the code works***? Uses a system call to 'pdftk' for bursting the PDF file into its constituent pages. Writes a .tex file which contains a \listoffigures command for the first page with the package hyperref ensuring it links to the figures. The later part of the .tex code contains several figure insertion statements where the PDF file corresponding to each page is inserted, providing captions only to those PDFs for which there is an entry in the provided TOC table.

***Why the code is not ideal?*** It relies on too many dependencies. It relies on a system call to the pdftk package, it requires that LaTeX be also installed on the machine with the graphics package. In the current version of the code, the PDFs on each page do have some offset which I am trying to solve using geometry package with custom margin settings. I will try to post the code once this problem is solved.

***A more ideal solution.*** That which does not require LaTeX and can use some PDF library within Python to achieve the same effect. Comments and suggestions welcome!